# jquery resizable bar which is responsive to window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**What I want to achieve ?**
Be to horizontally resizable but I've already done that.
To my resizable bar to be responsive to window size, at this moment It's not move at all, It stays at the same place all the time (except when I resize this ofc ;) )
*I need option to resize that form left to right*

**Issue**
When I set position to absolute, resize from left to right works fine, but It's not responsive. When I set It to responsive It's not responsive and can't resize from left to right. It always resize on right side.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').append('<div id="resizable"></div>');
  for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    $('#hours-row').append('<span class="hour hour-"' + (i + 6) + '>' + (i + 6) + '</span>');
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#resizable").resizable({
    grid: 15,
    animate: true,
    helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
    handles: 'e, w',
    minHeight: 30,
    maxHeight: 30
  });
});

var barGenerator = function(shopID, width, type, grid) {
  $(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
      grid: grid,
      animate: true,
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
      handles: 'e, w',
      minHeight: width,
      maxHeight: width
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#resizable {
  margin: auto;
  height: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #35ad1a;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.hours-bar {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: auto;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position: fixed;
}

#hours-row {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.hour {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-size: large;
}

.shop-work-hours-bar {
  width: 120px;
  background: #20b229;
}

.ui-resizable-helper {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css "/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="hours-row"></div>
<div id="resizable"></div>
```

Technology :
asp.net core 2.0, jquery, jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

You can use below handles:

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
   handles: 'e, w, sw'
});
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I had to put : position: absolute !important in css